# When the mouse leaves a button it dosen't correctly switches to "out"

Tags: phaser-framework

When the mouse enter on my button, the frame is changed for the overframe... But it doesn't go the outframe when the mouse leaves the button.

Here is my code :

```
this.button = this.game.add.button(this.game.world.centerX, 525, 'startBtn', this.actionOnClickStartButton, this, 1, 0, 0);
```

You can see it here : http://le-carre-noir.net/click-the-black-squares-beta/
I'm talking about the "GO" button...

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in v.2.0.6 of Phaser Framework, download at least 2.0.7 version, where this bug is fixed.